# What does set() in Python use to test equality between objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I have written some code in Python which has a class called product and overrided the magic functions `__eq__` and `__hash__`. Now I need to make a set which should remove duplicates from the list based on the `ID` of the product. As you can see the output of [this](https://ideone.com/JUymFw) code the hashes of two objects are the same, yet when i make a set of those two objects the length is 2 not one.

But, when i change the `__eq__` method of the code to this

```py
def __eq__(self, b) -> bool:
    if self.id == b.id:
        return True
    return False
```

and use it with the same hash function it works and the length of the set is 1. So i am confused whether the set data-structure uses the `__eq__` method to test for equality or the `__hash__` method.

Comment: Both. For an object to work correctly in a set or dict, it should have a suitable `__hash__` and `__eq__` method which are consistent with each other. Both are used.

Comment: To test for **equality**, you use `__eq__`. It is definitely possible that two **completely different** objects will have the same hash. Of course, a good hash function will avoid that but it is still possible

Comment: Have you not answered your own question with that experiment?

Comment: A typical hashtable will compute a hashcode first and then perform equality checks against objects with the same hashcode in case there are collisions.

Answer (score 1):

Equality tests can be expensive, so the set starts by comparing hashes. If the hashes are not equal, then the check ends. If the hashes are equal, the set then tests for equality. If it only used `__eq__`, it might have to do a lot of unnecessary work, but if it only used `__hash__`, there would be no way to resolve a hash collision.

Here's a simple example of using equality to resolve a hash collision. All integers are their own hashes, except for `-1`:

```
>>> hash(-1)
-2
>>> hash(-2)
-2
>>> s = set()
>>> s.add(-1)
>>> -2 in s
False
```

Here's an example of the set skipping an equality check because the hashes aren't equal. Let's subclass an `int` so it return a new hash every second:

```
>>> class TimedInt(int):
...  def __hash__(self):
...   return int(time.time())
...
>>> a = TimedInt(5)
>>> a == 5
True
>>> a == a
True
>>> s = set()
>>> s.add(a)  # Now wait a few seconds...
>>> a in s
False
```